# Portal for matching volunteer webmasters and non-profits?

Tags: social-media, hiring, non-profit

So, 1-2 years ago I recall hearing about a site that matches non-profits with volunteer webmasters. Does anyone know such a site?

Questions, feedback, requests -- just comment, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should take a look at [volunteermatch.org](http://www.volunteermatch.org/) and [idealist.org](http://www.idealist.org/).

Comment: +1 No, idea -- but those will work. Thanks!